# Google: Fix Mobile Usability Issues warning - Is Redirect Sufficient?

Tags: seo, htaccess, google-search, mobile

So recently Google sent out a mass warning to many of us to either fix Mobile Usability Issues on our website or risk having its rankings suffer.

> Google systems have tested 120 pages from your site and found that 99%
>   of them have critical mobile usability errors. The errors on these 119
>   pages severely affect how mobile users are able to experience your
>   website. These pages will not be seen as mobile-friendly by Google
>   Search, and will therefore be displayed and ranked appropriately for
>   smartphone users.

Fair enough: my primary website takes advantage of
PC Screen sizes and is not expected to be mobile-friendly. I created a
mobile site specifically for mobile users ages ago.

So here's what I want to know: I have a mobile site and a regular site and the appropriate RewriteRules and Conditions in my .htaccess file to redirect mobile device users to my Mobile Site. I've also prepared & submitted two sitemaps for Google: one for mydomain.com & one for my mobile site (m.mydomain.com). Need I do anything more? Because I really don't want to dumb down my primary site to make it fit on a mobile viewport. Thanks - any insights are greatly appreciated...

Comment: Yeah. Do not dumb-down your non-mobile site if you have a mobile site. I am interested in a good answer for this too. BTW- there is no penalty, it just won't perform as well for searches by mobile users. Important words here? By mobile users.

Comment: Have you used the correct rel="alternate" mark up for mobile pages either in the sitemaps or at a page level, and added the the canonical tags to the mobile pages? If not, I'll add an answer.

Comment: No, Max, I haven't & would love more info on what I should do & why. Thanks! :) Debbie

Comment: Hi Max! Thanks again for the suggestion. I found good information on your suggestion [at this Google Webmaster Mobile - SEO Configuration site](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls?hl=en). Wow! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just redirecting mobile users to the mobile site is good enough. In fact, I noticed on my adsense enabled site that my earnings have improved since I redirected my mobile users to the mobile site.

It would also be helpful too to add links to allow the user to visit the main (desktop PC) site from the mobile site and vice-versa.

Also, Try to make the mobile site work so it fits in a screen with a 320 pixel width and test it with google's page-speed insights.